# Java 8 isLeapYear implementation. What logical operator means?

Tags: java, api, java-8

I am looking into the java 8 implemenetions of Date API and found this

> Checks if the year is a leap year, according to the ISO proleptic
>   calendar system rules.
>
> This method applies the current rules for leap years across the whole
>   time-line. In general, a year is a leap year if it is divisible by
>   four without remainder. However, years divisible by 100, are not leap
>   years, with the exception of years divisible by 400 which are.
>
> For example, 1904 is a leap year it is divisible by 4. 1900 was not a
>   leap year as it is divisible by 100, however 2000 was a leap year as
>   it is divisible by 400.
>
> The calculation is proleptic - applying the same rules into the far
>   future and far past. This is historically inaccurate, but is correct
>   for the ISO-8601 standard.

```
public boolean isLeapYear(long prolepticYear) {
        return ((prolepticYear & 3) == 0) && ((prolepticYear % 100) != 0 || (prolepticYear % 400) == 0);
    }
```

> But give us prolepticYear & 3.

```
11111001111
    &
00000000011
00000000011
```

what means prolepticYear & 3.

Comment: `prolepticYear & 3` is equivalent to `prolepticYear % 4` (at least for years >= 0).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`prolepticYear & 3` let's put it slightly different. `3` in binary is `11`. Thus `prolepticYear` & `11` would be zero only when last two bits from `prolepticYear` are zeroes. (that's actually called a bit mask).

And now think a bit different too:

```
 0100 - (4 in decimal, has last two bits zero)
 1000 - (8 in decimal, has last two bits zero)
 1100 - (12 in decimal, has last two bits zero)

 ... these are numbers divisible by four
```

Usually the `&` operation is faster then `%`.

Sometimes `&` is used for other purposes too (`%` operation *may* yield negative numbers, while `&` will not - that's how a bucket inside a `HashMap` is chosen based on *possibly* negative values of `Key#hashcode`, but not the case here)

Answer (score 3):

`(prolepticYear & 3) == 0` checks whether the two least significant bits of `prolepticYear` are `0`.

This is equivalent to checking whether `prolepticYear` is divisible by 4.

In other words,

```
(prolepticYear & 3) == 0
```

is equivalent to

```
(prolepticYear % 4) == 0
```